# Is there a unique queue in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, queue

A unique queue would only allow the queueing of a value once. Subsequent queuing would not do anything.

If it is not clear what the uniqueness criteria is, there could be a key that would be added.

Is there such a data structure in Ruby?

Comment: Such as a [`Set`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.0.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html)?

Comment: I was looking for something thread-safe, but Set is pretty close.

Comment: Can the same element be added again after it was removed? Or do you expects the queue to “remember” all past elements?

Comment: @BSeven you can wrap a `Mutex#synchronize` around your getters/setters and it will be threadsafe

Comment: @Stefan - It can be re-added after it is removed.

Comment: @maxpleaner - I ended up using a Hash and Mutex and it works great.